# How to return to previous page with parameters?

Tags: angular

I want to return to previous page with some parameters. Any suggestion how can i do that?

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
   returnToPreviousPage(){
        this._location.back();
    }
```

So what i want is something like this :

```
this._location.back(id:123);
```

And when i back on page to have something like this : `www.test.com?d=123`

Comment: using `router.navigate` ?

Comment: i dont know from what page i come..and because of that i dont know where to redirect it

Comment: then how do you know what parameter to pass ?

Comment: i need to pass id .. that id will be handled on every page

Comment: then it is already stored in the history. I don't see the point. Please elaborate your question it is quite vague for now...

Comment: its not stored in history ... i want when i back to have url something like this: test.com?id= 12321313

Comment: this.router.navigate(['/heroes', { id: heroId, foo: 'foo' }]);

Comment: @selvassn like i said i dont know from what page i come so i dont know where to redirect it

Comment: Some like this you are expecting suppose you are on `test.com?id= 12321313` and you want to come back  `test2.com?id= 12321313`. Give and example in question to better understand you rather than theory

Comment: yes.. so when i go back i want to add params  ?id=1233123

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here if you are using the `this._location.back()` to go back you can pass only the index to this function. How much index you want to go back from browser history.

**For Example to go 2 index back**

```
this._location.back(2);
```

**Example to go back with queryParams**

```
this.router.navigate(['/test2', { id: 12321313}]);
```

Check for angular 2 declaration function location.back() inside `@angular\common.js`

```
class Location {
     /* Navigates back in the platform's history.*/
     /* @return {?} */

    back() { this._platformStrategy.back(); }
 }
```

InShort the thing what you are trying `this._location.back(2)` work same as window.history.back(); and accept only the index value you want to go back from browser history

Comment: if i use router.navigate i need to detect then from what page i come...because i can come from different pages

Comment: that not fix my problem

Comment: @None there is no way using `this._location.back()` to go back with query params