# Angular 5 - Return to previous state

Tags: typescript, routes, angular5

I have an Angular web app where I need to return to the previous state.  For example, say I am on a page found at http://localhost/someURL.  On this page, a user is able to search for items and is returned in a list format (someURL remains unchanged).  On each row is a button leading to another component found at http://localhost/someURL2.

My question is:  When a user clicks a cancel button at someURL2, how do I return to someURL with the search results still there?  I am able to go back to someURL (see code below) but the search results are not saved.

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
......
})

export class SomeClass implements OnInit {

constructor(private location: Location) { }

backToPrevious(){  
this.location.back(); //Does not show search results upon return
 }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return to previous page with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44628417/how-to-return-to-previous-page-with-parameters)

Comment: I don't believe it is a duplicate.  That post describes a url with parameters where this post details a URL that doesn't change when the search results data is loaded on same page

Comment: In order to get your previous page filled with results, you must pass your search params via storage or route params in order to construct your page. Either this or make your details content a modal and not a page without changing route.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the filters params and override the `onInit` function in the first controller.
In this function you should get data from your `localStorage` and call the filter function with that params.

This is the function that you should create in the first controller:

```
ngOnInit() {
    // Get params from localstorage
    // Call function that restore filters
}
```